# Integrate step function and characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let be $f_{k} = \frac{1}{k} \mathbb{1}_{[-k,k]}$ and $f_k: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

How i can show that $f_{k}$ is integrable $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$? and HOW to compute this?

- $f_{k}$ is a step function and thats why it should be integrable. Because we define the integrale of a step function $\varphi$ as follows $\int \varphi := \sum_{y\in\varphi(X)}y\mu (\left \{\varphi^{-1}({y})\right \}), \varphi: X \rightarrow [0,\infty]$

It would be nice, if someone could explain me so that i can solve the other two functions by myself. $g_{k} = k\mathbb{1}_{[0,1/k]}$ and $h_{k} = \frac{1}{k^2}\mathbb{1}_{[0,k]}$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_k$ is integrable (for $k>0$) because $f_k=\frac{1}{k} 1_{[-k,k]}\leq1_{[-k,k]}$ which is integrable.

To compute it you can just use your definition of the integral of a step function:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_k d\lambda=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{k} 1_{[-k,k]}  d\lambda=\frac{1}{k} \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{[-k,k]}  d\lambda=\frac{1}{k} \lambda([-k,k])=\frac{1}{k}\cdot 2k=2$

Comment: aah, thanks! then the integral of gk should be  k*1/k = 1 and for hk, 1/k^2 * k = 1/k.